# UserProfile(user_id=2) returns <UserProfile: user>, but UserProfile(user_id=2).birth_year returns None

Tags: python, django

I have the below model, and am trying these two commands in the [django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#shell):

1. `from auth_lifecycle.models import UserProfile`
2. `UserProfile(user_id=2).birth_year`

But it's returning `None`, despite `UserProfile(user_id=2)` returning `<UserProfile: user>`.

Here is the query confirming the data exists:

```
 auth_lifecycle_db=# select * from auth_lifecycle_userprofile;
  id | birth_year | user_id
 ----+------------+---------
   1 |       1905 |       1
   2 |       1910 |       2
 (2 rows)
```

How do I access the birth_year attribute?

---

models.py

```
"""Defines a single extra user-profile field for the user-authentication
    lifecycle demo project: Birth year
"""
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db                  import models


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Extra information about a user: Birth year and profile picture. See
        the package doc for more info.

        ---NOTES---

        Useful related SQL:
            - `select id from auth_user where username <> 'admin';`
            - `select * from auth_lifecycle_userprofile where user_id=(x,x,...);`
    """
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    birth_year = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Year you were born")

    # Override the __str__() method to return out something meaningful
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `objects` attribute to access the database values.

```
UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=2).birth_year
```

or

```
User.objects.get(id=2).profile.birth_year
```

All your code does is create a local instance of `UserProfile` with `user_id=2`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-attributes